# missing to target the correct element traversing up the dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a HTML structure like the following (relevant part):

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card card-warning">something here</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card">something else here</div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to remove the class `card-warning` from the first card and add it to the second on toggle of a radio button (one in each card).

The code I have so far adds correctly the class to the second card but fails to remove it from the first.

```
$(this).closest('div.card').addClass('card-warning').prev('div.card').removeClass('card-warning');
```

`$(this)` is the selected radio button and `.closest('div.card').addClass('card-warning')` correctly adds the class as expected. The point is that `.prev('div.card').removeClass('card-warning')` is not targeting the previous card.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could you post the html structure with radios to try a snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest `div.card` you're selecting does not have any previous siblings, so the `.prev` fails. Navigate to the previous element of the *parent* element instead:

```
$(this)
  .closest('div.card')
  .addClass('card-warning')
  .parent()
  .prev()
  .children('div.card')
  .removeClass('card-warning');
```

```js
$('#foo').on('click', function() {
  $(this)
    .closest('div.card')
    .addClass('card-warning')
    .parent()
    .prev()
    .children('div.card')
    .removeClass('card-warning');
});
```

```css
.card-warning {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card card-warning">something here</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card" id="foo">something else here</div>
</div>
```

If you'll only have one `.card-warning` in the DOM at any given time, instead of dynamically navigating to parents/siblings etc, just select the one element with `.card-warning` in the DOM first:

```
$('.card-warning').removeClass('card-warning');
$(this)
  .closest('div.card')
  .addClass('card-warning');
```

Comment: it works if I want to switch from the first to the second but not the way back (obviously). Since it should toggle between the two contents is there a way to make `.parent().prev()` generically find the "other" div that has this class?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this what you you search but below snippet , show example

- first add class to closest div card
- then remove class from other div.card except current using

  .parents('.row').find('div.card').not($(this).parents('div.card'))

```js
$(function() {

  $(".apply").on("click", function() {
    $(this).closest('div.card').addClass('card-warning').parents('.row').find('div.card').not($(this).parents('div.card')).removeClass("card-warning");

  })

})
```

```css
.apply {
  margin-left:20px;
  color: red;
}

.card-warning {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="card card-warning">something here <input name="apply" class="apply" type="radio"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="card">something else here <input name="apply" class="apply" type="radio"/></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  

</div>
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for on a general purpose. In this case since there can be only one div with this class I used the workaround on the other answer

Comment: @LelioFaieta , Okey great  :)